# use resource file data annotation in custom attribute

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I used resource file in the view model and also used a custom attribute for the binding drop-down of view model.
I need to add key and value in that for ex. (1,(resource file value)) can i achieve this?

### I tried:

```
[AdditionalMetadata("ControlId", "1")]
[Display(Name = "VolunteerID",ResourceType = typeof(ECTMSResource))]
```

### and I want:

```
[AdditionalMetadata("1",Resource file value)]
```

Comment: What is `Resource file value`?

Comment: my display name is VolunteerID and value in resource file is 'Volunteer Id' like wise.